# Output of program depends on arbitrary print statements?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have a Fortran 95 code whose output seems to be a function of things that it shouldn't be a function of. Specifically, the following scenerio is happening:

- Run code with version A; it doesn't work (I mean, it works as in it compiles and runs, but it doesn't give the result I expect)
- Run code with Version B; it works. Version B contains only trivial modifications to version A such as print statements or small changes in numerical values of variables.
- Run code with version A; all of a sudden, it works.

I think there's some issue with memory or using variables before they're initialized, so I was wondering whether or not there was a way to check this sort of thing with `gfortran`, or if any one knows what the problem might be. I've tried `gfortran my_program.f95 -Wall - Wextra`, but it just gives me a bunch of complaints about nonconforming tab characters.

Comment: I suggest you try switching on run-time array-bounds checking (I think the compiler flag is `-fbounds-check` for gfortran but it's not a compiler I use regularly so consult the documentation).  As you have concluded, if inserting print statements seems to fix your program there is definitely something wrong; in my experience walking off the end of an array is one of the possible causes of the symptoms you report.

Comment: Hmm, that's a good point, but `-fbounds-check` didn't seem to have any problems.

Comment: In that case figure out the compiler option to check routine interfaces at compile time.  I don't know what that option might be.  Don't trust your intuition if it tells you that `-Wall` turns on all compile-time warnings, it probably doesn't.

Comment: Okay, so I completely restructured the program, declared the intent of every variable, and put every procedure in a module. From [this](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gfortran) site, the compiler option `-Wimplicit-interface` checks to see if a procedure is called without an explicit interface and now it returns no warnings. I thought such pedantry would fix the issue, but apparently not.

Comment: You can probe the initialisation idea a bit more by compiling with `-finit-real=snan -finit-integer=-999` along with `-g -ffpe-trap=invalid,zero -fbounds-check`.  The idea is to force the code to fail if variables are used before they've been explicitly initialised.  Of course, this may just produce a fog of irrelevant exceptions if your code relies on implicit initialisation in general.

Comment: None of those commands had any complaints, so does that mean that everything's fine on the initialization front?

Comment: You already said, you suspect memory issues. Did you try `valgrind`? I'm surprised, this hasn't been mentioned yet... (ok... maybe because your question states "with gfortran"...)

Comment: No complaints from valgrind's basic memcheck either. I think I might try running the program on another computer, but aside from that it's looking like a lost cause.

Comment: No idea, why the second run of version A should work, but if you use any optimisation flags, the compiler might do something overly aggressive resulting in bad code. With prints and the likes, these optimizations might not be possible for the compiler anymore. If this is the case, you can try to identify the code part, where the optimizations produce wrong code, and optimize it yourself, helping the compiler and avoiding the bad code generation.

Comment: Another good idea, but I'm not using any optimization flags. I also ran it on another computer and it had the same problem. *sigh* ...

Comment: Do you have a different compiler you might be able to try it with? Or perhaps trying different levels of -O or -g could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a while ago, but I fixed the problem so I figured I might as well post it. To be honest, I'm not sure whether or not these steps in particular are what fixed it, but it works, so here they are:

1. Put all procedures in modules (this also helps to organize the code) as opposed to just "out in the open."
2. Declare the intent (`in`, `out` or `inout`) of all variables via `real, intent(in) :: foo`. This is obviously useful for optimization and organization but apparently it has something to do with interfaces as well ... no idea what that's about.

And that's it!